# What is equivalent resistance equation in this case?

Tags: current, resistance, parallel, series, resistivity

If we have three resistors (A, B & C) and we know that A is connected in parallel with B and also A is connected in series with C. How can we write the equation of the R equivalent of the three resistors in this case?.
Edit: I would like to highlight that this is not an actual electrical circuit. It is something related to measuring the electrical conductivity in rocks where the distribution of different rock types makes the first type (A) acts as a resistor in parallel with another rock type (B) and at the same time (A) is connected in series with a third rock type (C). Hereunder is a picture of what I mean.
[image]

Comment: Can you draw the circuit you mean when you say "A is in parallel with B and also A is in series with C"? Because actually it isn't possible for those both to be true.

Comment: It is actually not an actual electrical circuit. It is something related to measuring the electrical conductivity in rocks where the distribution of different rock types makes the first type (A) acts as a resistor in parallel with another rock type (B) and at the time (A) is connected in series with a third rock type (C).

Comment: Can you draw a picture of what you mean, because I can interpret that at least two different ways (and the results will change depending)?  i.e. Is (B) also in parallel with (C)?

Comment: @evildemonic This is a picture of what I mean https://imgur.com/a/uhsFn3Z The current is passing through three different rock types which act as three different resistors. How can we write the equivalent resistance equation for this configuration?

Comment: @evildemonic Excuse me I made a mistake in drawing the previous picture. This is the picture of the right configuration https://imgur.com/MTuFE0j

Comment: Can the current flow sideways between A & B and between B & C? If it can then you'll probably need to define the geometry and use a field solver to find the answer.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany  This is a picture of what I mean https://imgur.com/MTuFE0j. If we assume that the current can't flow sideways, how can we figure out the equivalent resistance equation?

Comment: It doesn't have a simple solution.

Comment: @OmarMohamed I am curious where the points of contact are located and the fuller 3D shape.

Comment: it is a 3D resistor grid

Comment: here is an off the wall thought ... I was reading posts at the robotics SE and I saw this  https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/21350/reinforcement-train-butterfly-robot-in-virtual-reality ... the answer at that post mentioned `computantional fluid dynamics` ... my thoughts linked to your post ... perhaps the way to solve your question is by using fluid dynamics ... each rock type would have different permeability

Answer (score 0):

> we know that A is connected in parallel with B and also A is connected in series with C.

This isn't possible.

When we say "A is in parallel with B" we mean that each end of A is connected to one of the ends of B.

And when we say "A is in series with C" we mean that one end of A is connected to one end of C **with nothing else connected at that same point**.

So if we have A and C in series, and then connect B in parallel with A, then A and C are no longer in series.

*Edit*

In comments you clarified your arrangement is like this:
[image]

and current can't flow sideways.

In that case, A and C are in series. B is in parallel with the combination of A and C.

So the total resistance is given by

$$R=\frac{R_B(R_A+R_C)}{R_B+(R_A+R_C)}.$$

In the real world, assuming that current can't flow sideways might be leading you to an inaccurate estimate of the resistance.

Comment: It is actually not an actual electrical circuit. It is something related to measuring the electrical conductivity in rocks where the distribution of different rock types makes the first type (A) acts as a resistor in parallel with another rock type (B) and at the time (A) is connected in series with a third rock type (C). Is there any way to find the equation of the R equivalent of the three resistors (rock types) with such configuration?

Comment: This is a picture of what I mean https://imgur.com/MTuFE0j

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would be your configuration.
[image: Resistors]

Comment: The solution is not this simple.

Answer (score 0):

If the current can only flow left-right, then the resistance R is simply

R= 1/(1/Rb + 1/(Ra + Rc))

But I have doubts this is actually a useful equation for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you write the same equation in terms of conductance?

Comment: Conductance is the reciprocal of resistance so it's a simple change.